# Opening a cut and seeing background

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working at a game and I have a cardboard in front at a wall. I want to cut the cardboard and open it with some clips. When the cut is opening I want to see the wall.

How can I achieve that efect?

I have tried shape tweening, but I can't apply it on texture onely a simple shape with a simple color or a gradient.

Comment: What have your tried?  Your question is too broad/vague in its current form for StackOverflow.  Consider expanding on the problem and showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: Are you attempting this with code or on the timeline? As LDMS said, please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: It sounds you need a mask?   You can use a shape tween as a mask for a textured object below the mask.  There are tutorials a plenty on how to use masks in FlashPro/AS3